# Content Builder REST API - Retrieve Email and approvals

Tags: rest-api, email, api, approval-process, content-builder

Does anyone know how to retrieve email and its approval status? I checked on marketing cloud documentation but couldn't find the property to do so.

I am trying to retrieve and filter for email that already has been approved and those under approval, for instance.

Link Marketing Cloud [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/email.htm?search_text=email)

Comment: Actually, retrieve is not the problem here. once I can get them through `GET /hub/v1/approvals`. But what I am trying to do is to structure my call to Updated an email approval. `"approvalStatus":{ "id":3,"name":"Pending Rework","displayName": "Pending Rework" }`, to `"id:" 4`, for example, that is Approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it.

For retrieving: 
**GET** `{{hostEndpoint}}/asset/v1/content/assets/{{emailId}}`

For Updating an email:
**PATCH** `{{hostEndpoint}}/asset/v1/content/assets/{{emailId}}`

In my case updating the Email Status:

> - The Initial state, when the email is just created
> - Also when the email is withdrawn

```
{    
    "data" : {
        "approvals" : {
            "approvalStatus": { "id" : 1,
                                "name" : "Draft" }
        }
    }
}
```

> - This is when the user starts the approval process
> - But also when the user completes the rework (next topic)

```
{    
    "data" : {
        "approvals" : {
            "approvalStatus": { "id" : 2,
                                "name" : "Pending" }
        }
    }
}
```

> - This is when the user submits some comments

```
{
    "data" : {
        "approvals" : {
            "approvalStatus": { "id" : 3,
                                "name" : "Pending Rework" }
        }
    }
}
```

> - And finally when the user approves the Email

```
{
    "data" : {
        "approvals" : {
            "approvalStatus": { "id" : 4,
                                "name" : "Approved" }
        }
    }
}
```